# How to access a letter within an array element (string) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Given an array:

```
var top3Scientists = [ "Hawking", "Newton", "Tesla" ];
```

If I type `top3Scientists[1]`, I get `"Newton"`. How can I access single letters of an array element, i.e., `"N"`?

Comment: `top3Sceintists[1].getCharAt(0)`?

Comment: You using bracket notation on the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
top3Sceintists[1] = "Newton"
```

then `top3Sceintists[1][0]` or `top3Sceintists[1].getCharAt(0)` will give you `N`

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/6qpskec9/)**

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. Here's a screenshot =

Comment: Where is the screenshot?